# Repeat animation every 5 seconds using Animate.css

Tags: css, animate.css

Let's say I have this HTML:

`<a id="btn-shake" class="animated shake" href="#">CONTINUE</a>`

and this CSS:

```
a#btn-shake {
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    clear: both;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px auto;

    animation-duration: 1s;
    -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;

    animation-delay: 1s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;

    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

and I want to repeat this shaking animation, but not continuously. I want to shake it once and than wait for 5 seconds and shake it again and then wait for 5 seconds and shake etc.

But I don't know how to do that.

Is it possible with animate.css and pure css? How to do that?

Answer (score 4):

One way to achieve this would be to build the delay into the animation itself. Something like the following:

```
a#btn-shake {
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    clear: both;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px auto;

    animation-name: shake-with-delay;
    animation-duration: 6s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes shake-with-delay {
    from, 16%, to {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
    1.6%, 4.8%, 8%, 11.2%, 14.4% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(-10px, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(-10px, 0, 0);
    }
    3.2%, 6.4%, 9.6%, 12.8% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(10px, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(10px, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

The biggest downside of this approach is that the percentages are closely coupled to the durations you want to implement.

Alternately, if you’re OK with a JavaScript solution, you could do something like the following:

```
function doAnimation(id, animName, duration, delay) {
    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    var timer;
    function addClass() {
        el.classList.add(animName);
    }
    function removeClass() {
        el.classList.remove(animName);
    }
    setInterval(function () {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        addClass();
        timer = setTimeout(removeClass, duration);
    }, duration + delay);
}

doAnimation('btn-shake', 'shake', 1000, 5000);
```

The advantage of the JS solution is that you can control any of the animations from animate.css independently and easily change the durations.

Comment: Here's a CodePen showing how it works: http://codepen.io/segdeha/pen/rLdkNV

Comment: Hmm, thanks, but it is weird. It doesn't look like shake animation and there is some "glitch" when it fall a little in the end. Isn't there some other option how to do this?

Comment: I fixed the animation to prevent the 'fall' glitch. You can change the transforms to get whatever effect you want.

Comment: This answer doesn't include the shake animation from animate.css.

Comment: Ah, my bad. I’m not familiar with animate.css.

Comment: @naveen This shake is different from the shake the OP was asking about.

Comment: @AndrewHedges: `@keyframes shake {
    from,
    to {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
    10%,
    30%,
    50%,
    70%,
    90% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(-10px, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(-10px, 0, 0);
    }
    20%,
    40%,
    60%,
    80% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(10px, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(10px, 0, 0);
    }
}` this is the css they use

Comment: @Godisgood: OP might have meant, or pure css. the question was tagged javascript n jquery

Comment: @naveen ahh i see.

Comment: Updated the answer and CodePen to emulate the shake animation in Animate.css

Comment: Here’s a CodePen showing the JavaScript solution in action: http://codepen.io/segdeha/pen/grZdGE

Answer (score 1):

With JavaScript, you could listen for the anamationEnd event of the element to fire, remove the shake animation, then add shake class back to element with a setTimeout.

first you will need to set up a function to listen to the different browser animation end events.

```
var pfx = ["webkit", "moz", "MS", "o", ""];    
function prefixedEventListener(element, type, callback) {
    for (var p = 0; p < pfx.length; p++) {
        if (!pfx[p]) type = type.toLowerCase();
        element.addEventListener(pfx[p]+type, callback, false);
    }
}
```

Then grab your button with a variable.

```
var btnShake = document.querySelector("#btnShake");
```

Finally call the prefix event listener function passing in the button, what you are listening for, and what to do once the event fires off.

```
prefixedEventListener(btnShake ,"AnimationEnd",function(e){
    btnShake.classList.remove("shake");
    setTimeout(function(){btnShake.classList.add("shake");}, 5000);

});
```

For more on this topic, see this [article](http://callmenick.com/post/listen-for-css-animation-events-with-javascript).